# C preprocessor with if statement

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

I have the following macro:

```
#define IF_TRACE_ENABLED(level)  if (IsTraceEnabled(level))
```

The user code should look following:

```
IF_TRACE_ENABLED(LEVEL1)
{
    ... some very smart code
}
```

The emphasis here on curly brackets - I want to prevent "if" from macro to "eat" other code:

```
if (...)
   IF_TRACE_ENABLED(LEVEL1)
      printf(....);
else
   bla bla bla
```

In this example `IF_TRACE_ENABLED` "eats" else block.

Is there way to enforce user code not compile without curly brakes or there are other to define the macro to achieve the safety?

Comment: I don't see what that macro gives you over the bare if statement.

Comment: Forget about this example. You could have a complicated condition in that `if` that you don't want to repeat each time.

Comment: @JeremyP: there's not much utility in having a macro for this simple example, but as Nathan indicates it's possible that there might be more complexity in the debugging macro and/or that there are several variations of the macro based on build configuration (for example, a release version that always evaluates to `false` so the trace strings are stripped from the executable).

Comment: Well why not just have a macro for the conditional i.e. the boolean expression inside the if.

Comment: @JeremyP: there are many ways to get a similar result, and using a macro for the condition is one that I like (but you might be surprised how many people don't). Here's an article on my lame blog: http://blog.nth-element.com/?p=3. You're right that the macro in the question might not have a lot of reason to exist on its own in the simple form in the question. But, I've seen similar macros used in the wild, usually as one of a set of debug macros with different definitions depending on build config. I think that having a technique for dealing with the problem posed in the question has value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This doesn't force the user of the macro to use braces, but it will prevent an `else` clause from being unintentionally eaten:

```
#define IF_TRACE_ENABLED(level)  if (!IsTraceEnabled(level)) {} else
```

A side note: braces around the `printf()` in the second example of the question wouldn't have fixed the problem - the `else` associated with `bla bla bla` would still be bound to the `if` statement in the macro.

Comment: Trying and failing to come up with a way this could backfire. +1

Comment: Where is content of "if" block is passed?

Comment: in the else block; nice answer!

Comment: @dimba: The test has been inverted, so that the contents of the block are executed by the `else`.

Comment: @Chris Lutz:  it fails if the user decided they wanted an else i.e. if they wanted `IF_TRACE_ENABLED(level) ... else { ... }`

Comment: @JeremyP: that's probably an unlikely use case, and I'd probably argue that instead of a failure, it's 'as designed'. If there is a use case for supporting an else clause, another macro or set of macros can be created to support it.

Comment: @Michael Burr: there's not really a use case for this monstrosity in the first place.  C has a perfectly good if control structure without creating new and broken ones.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
#define IF_TRACE_ENABLED(level) do { if(IsTraceEnabled(level)) {
#define END_TRACE_ENABLED } } while(0);
```

I don't think there's any way to "enforce" good syntax from only the opening line of the macro. You will need to use two.

**EDIT**

I've added an extra pair of braces inside the macro to avoid all ambiguity.

In response to the comment, this macro is meant to be used like this:

```
IF_TRACE_ENABLED(LEVEL1)
    printf("Trace\n");
END_TRACE_ENABLED
```

Not as a statement. For the record, I think this is an abuse of the preprocessor and nobody should do this at all. What's wrong with just writing it out, bracketed with `#ifdef DEBUG` if necessary.

Comment: The only thing I don't like in the solution is indentation of the block between stat and stop macros - your editor won't indent it.

Comment: is it not possible to simply use the braces, without do & while?

Comment: @ptmato - there's something in what @crypto says. do/while is used to enfore macro to look like normal function, by that that he's enforced to use ";" in the end. So ";" in the end of macro is redundant.

Any way we don't ";" since the macro doesn't look like a function call

Comment: @dimba, this isn't meant to be used with a semicolon at the end. See edit.

Comment: @crypto, probably. I just thought this would be less likely to have a corner case where it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to predicate the execution of a statement/block based on the evaluation of a macro, that dangling else is a risky latent bug that I've seen a lot of teams just live with.

The other solutions presented alter the structure of the code or are otherwise awkward in some fashion. The solution presented below isn't perfect - it has its own awkwardness, but hopefully it is more livable flavor of awkward.

One can generally transform a preprocessor macro's output from the simple but risky form of

```
if (expression)
```

to a `for` loop that will execute 0 or 1 times depending upon `expression`. As a loop, there's no risk of dangling else. This works like so:

```
for (bool _internal_once = true; _internal_once && (expression); _internal_once = false)
```

Note that `expression` could very well be a complex expression being text substituted, so we need the loop condition to be `_internal_once && (expression)` to both avoid operator precedence issues, and also guarantee `expression` is only evaluated once (due to C boolean short circuit logic).

The awkwardness of this solution is that is changes the `break` and `continue` behavior within predicated code, made worse because the loop is hidden and it is easy to forget. This has not yet been a problem in real world usage for me.  We use these predicate macros to guard metrics, logging, telemetry, and other support code that doesn't often interact with an outer loop.

I have been bit by a real world problem in a previous incarnation of this loop. Never NEVER **NEVER** use a simple name for the loop control variable, I've seen it shadow another variable and cause the statement/block to see the wrong value.

This solution doesn't force the use of a block/braces on the client's code, but arguably since C and C++ don't, neither should you. It's the client's choice/policy.

One could argue you should generate a more unique name for the loop variable, concatenating `##` the identifier with a suffix of `__LINE__` or `__COUNTER__` (for gnu). That feels excessive to me, the loop control variables are all local/`auto` and should shadow correctly.

You can even implement predicates like

- DO_ONCE

  - Run only once
  - `for (static bool _internal_once = true; _internal_once; _internal_once = false)`
- DO_EVERY_N(N)

  - Runs once per N iterations
- DO_EVERY_MS(MS)

  - Won't run again until at least MS milliseconds has passed

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but you'll have the pass the contents of the if block as an argument to the macro as  well:

```
#define IF_TRACE_ENABLED(level,content)  { if (IsTraceEnabled(level)) {content} }
```

Comment: This is not necessary printf(...). This could be any code that should be evaluated only when macro condition is true.

Comment: You should add a block around content.

Comment: @Ronny - this is what I want to enforce user, so if he forgets to do it, the compilation will fail

Comment: passing content to macro could be complicated and will influence user - we need be careful with commas in content not to be interpreted as macro argument separator, what if I want comment line to be part of comment.

Comment: @dimba it wouldn't fail this way